# Binary search of string array in C

Tags: c, binary-search

I want to write a binary search for a string array in C.

I have written this code and it compiles with no errors but when i try to search it gives no results. Any help would be appreciated.

String is a type def. Sorry for not clarifying this in the beginning.

```
//Looks up word s, in dictionary.
bool lookup(string s)
{  
    int min = 0;
    int max = dictionary.size - 1;
    int mid;
    bool found = false;

    while (min <= max && !found)
    {
        mid = (min + max) /2;
        if (dictionary.words[mid].letters == s)
            found = true;
        else if (dictionary.words[mid].letters > s)
            max = mid -1;
        else
            min = mid + 1;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: How is this `C`?  Is `string` a typedeff'ed struct, or is this `C++`?

Comment: Are you using C or C++? You can't use `std::string` in C, and if you're using cstrings (arrays of `char`), you can't use `==` to compare them (or, at least not the way you think).

Comment: The algorithm looks correct.Point us to the code if you need help.

Comment: i found this much more as c# code

Comment: Step through it with a debugger when you know what result you are expecting, and see how and when the behaviour differs from what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

String in C are just char arrays, and since comparison between arrays using `==` only compares the start address, you need to use the librray function [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) in `string.h` to compare the contents of the arrays. Like so:

```
if (strcmp(dictionary.words[mid].letters, s) == 0)
```

**EDIT**

I see that despite the `c` tag, you have some sort of `string` type. Is this C or C++?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help if you pasted the string and the dictionary structures.

Assuming that the Dictionary is a sorted array of words.Strings (array of char) and string is a array of char as well then I would assume that when you do `dictionary.words[int].letters` 
the return type is a memory and same is the case with `s`. As the two strings are saved at different memory locations you are unable to find the string.

Try iterating through the string to compare the strings

```
bool lookup(string s)
{  
    int min = 0;
    int max = dictionary.size - 1;
    int mid;
    bool found = false;
    int i;
    int length = 0;                 //calculate the length of the input string
    while (s[length] != '\0')
    {
    length++;
    }

    while (min <= max && !found)
    {
        mid = (min + max) /2;
        for(i=0;i<length;i++)
        {
            if(dictionary.words[mid].letters[i] == '\0')
                break;
            if (dictionary.words[mid].letters[i] == s[i])
                continue;
            else if (dictionary.words[mid].letters[i] > s[i])
                max = mid -1;
            else
                min = mid + 1;
            break;
        }
        if(i==length)
            found=true;
    }
    return found;
}
```

I have not compiled the code but this should give you the gist.